# System.Reflection.PropertyInfo Array

Tags: .net, system.reflection

After Getting a System.Reflection.PropertInfo array for a class- Does anyone know how or if this array is sorted or do I have to Array.Sort(MySortMethods/Params)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're getiing the `PropertyInfo` array by calling [`GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx), in which case the ordering of the array isn't guaranteed.

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx):

> The `GetProperties` method does not
>   return properties in a particular
>   order, such as alphabetical or
>   declaration order. Your code must not
>   depend on the order in which
>   properties are returned, because that
>   order varies.

Comment: Ah! Precisely! Thanks, I Seemed to have overlooked that in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the documentation for the method you're using to get the PropertyInfos.  If it doesn't state anything about the ordering of results I would assume they are not ordered and order them myself as you suggest.